# Why doesn't my exe file open from the debug or release folder for visual studio 2015?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2015, directory, exe, release

I'm still new to visual studio and I'm desperately trying to find a way to run my simple console application (in c) from an exe file. I have found my debugging and release folders, each folder containing ilk,pdb, iobj, and ipdb along with the exe file. This is probably a very simple answer so please keep it on a basic level of understanding, thanks :c

Comment: So what is your question? You've said you've found the .exe file in both the debug and release folder. What seems to be the problem you're having? You've not explained how you're attempting to run your .exe or what problem you're having doing so.

Comment: Well.... If you read the title, you would have seen my question, "Why doesn't my exe file open from the debug or release folder for visual studio 2015?"

Comment: And if you read my comments, you would have seen that I asked you to clarify some **specific points** about that vague question. Please [edit] your question to be **specific** about how you're trying to run your executable, and what **specific** issue you're having with doing so. We're not sitting at your machine to figure out what it is you're asking, and we can't read your mind from where we are. If you want help, **be clear about the problem you're experiencing**. Rather than being snippy, [edit] your question and explain the problem you're having, and someone can probably help you.

Comment: Well... I hover my cursor over the exe file located in either the debug folder or the release folder of visual studio 2015. Then I press the left mouse button twice (Its called double-clicking, it usually opens files if you're unfamiliar with that process). Then nothing happens. Was that specific enough for you?

Comment: OK. If you insist on being rude, I'll just vote to close the question as unclear. Your attitude and insulting conduct isn't going to get you very far here. Good luck. You're going to need it. You're the one asking **us** for **free help** solving **your problem**. There's no need for you to take any sort of attitude here. But I can see already I have no reason to want to provide you with any assistance. As I said, good luck.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see how this question is difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write in C++ or in C, you could add the code "system("pause");". It would not close the console window directly if you double click the .exe file in your project output path.

A simple sample here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F82W3pv87Hk

Answer (score 1):

maybe you already run .exe by double click it, but after it finished running and gone.
you should add sentence like:
Console.ReadLine();

in your code.